# Does $\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\ k^p +(-1)^k}$ converge for $ 1\geq p$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does $\sum _{k=2} ^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\ k^p +(-1)^k}$ converge for $ 1\geq  p$ ?

for $p= \frac{1}{2}$ it is divergent because with Taylor series :

\begin{align*}
\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}+(-1)^n} &= \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\left( 1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right) \\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} -\frac{1}{n} + \left[ \frac{(-1)^n}{n^{3/2}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)  \right]
\end{align*}
The (series of the) first term converges conditionally, the second diverges, the third converges absolutely.

Comment: You're developing a series, but then you deal with "the series of the first term, the series of the second term...? How does this work and is it relevant at all?

Comment: What @Joanpemo said. If you separate your series into sum of several series then the convergence or divergence of any of them will tell you exactly nothing about your original series

Answer (score 0):

It has to be $\;p\ge0\;$ , otherwise putting $\;q=-p>0\;$ :

$$\frac{(-1)^k}{k^p+(-1)^k}=\frac{(-1)^kk^q}{1+(-1)^kk^q}\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0$$

Now, observe that the sequence $\;\left\{\,\frac1{k^p+(-1)^k}\,\right\}_{k=1}^\infty\;$ is positive and eventually monotonic

descending to zero (since $\;k^p(k-1)\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}\infty\;$ , for $\;p>0\;$ ) , and the series $\;\sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k\;$ is bounded , so by [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) your series converges.

Answer (score 0):

check this:
multiplying by $$n^p-(-1)^n$$
you get:
$$(n^p(-1)^n-1)/((n^p)^2-1)$$
you can separate the expression you get in two series with these two general terms:
$$(n^p(-1)^n)/((n^p)^2-1)$$
$$(-1)/((n^p)^2-1)$$ 
Using Alternating series test (Leibniz) in the first one you can assure that this part converges. BUT the second one only converges when $2p>1$ (due to its relation to Harmonic series)